# custom inputs of simple form for images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

in my form, i let user upload a file (image), it looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @team] do |f|
    = f.input :logo, as: :photo
    = image_tag @team.logo.url if @team.logo?
    = f.hidden_field :logo_cache
```

and now i want to create custom input just for photos, it should include hidden field and displaying image.

```
class PhotoInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input
    @builder.file_field(attribute_name, input_html_options).html_safe
  end
end
```

this is my basics, i have problems with this input, because it doesnt seem to know methods image_tag or even link_to...